# Are irreducible components of regularly embedded varieties regularly embedded?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a (reduced) subvariety $V \hookrightarrow X$ of a smooth variety $X$ such that $V$ is regularly embedded in $X$. (i.e. is locally cut out by a regular sequence of $\operatorname{codim}(V)$ functions, or equivalently the normal cone $N_{X}(V)$ is a vector bundle).

Further suppose that the variety $V$ is a union of two irreducible components $V = V_1 \cup V_2$. Is it always true that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are regularly embedded in $X$? Do we need a transversality condition on their intersection?

My approach so far has been to assume that
$$a_1, \ldots, a_k$$
is the regular sequence in $\mathcal{O}_{x,X}$ cutting out $V$ at $x\in V_1 \cap V_2\subset X$, where $k = \operatorname{codim}(V)$ and ask how we can modify this regular sequence to get functions only vanishing at one of $V_1$ and $V_2$ but so far I have not had success.

Comment: Given ANY subvariety $V$ (locally), one can find a complete intersection with $V$ as a component. So, start with a $V$ which is not regularly embedded.

Comment: @Mohan what if we assume that the irreducible components intersect transversally?

Comment: What does transversal mean for you, if the varieties are singular?